# Momet JS: How to get calendar options based on locale

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How can i get moment's calendar string options based on the selected locale:

for example, the default `en` locale as described here [Moment Calendar Time](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/) is:

```
{
    sameDay: '[Today]',
    nextDay: '[Tomorrow]',
    nextWeek: 'dddd',
    lastDay: '[Yesterday]',
    lastWeek: '[Last] dddd',
    sameElse: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
}
```

How to get these options for different locales?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this to get calendar's locale data options:

```js
moment().localeData()._calendar
```